# 1:N relationship where N must be at least one entry

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Hi there I have a short question about database design. I also tried the search but can't find what I am looking for. So here is my question:

I have two database tables *Idea* and *Media* (1:N). So basically this means one idea can have none, one or several medias. BUT I asked myself if it's possible to define the table that each idea must have at least one media. If this is possible how can I achieve this with MS SQL Server 2008?

I hope somebody can help me out.

Thx alot for your help

**UPDATE:**
this is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you could do this with keeping `Media` in a separate table: how will you insert the data? You have to insert into one table first, then into the second.  What you can try doing is putting the first `Media` into the `Idea` (de-normalising) and declaring the fields as `not null` - but I wouldn't recommend it.  You may be better off with some logic in the code rather than database.

Comment: I agree with Aleks. I think this is a business rule that belongs in a middle tier somewhere, not in the database.

Comment: @Aleks attaching a FK NOT NULL from Idea to Media is not uncommon.  It's simple, and yes he will need to populate Media first.

Comment: @David: I disagree.  This is simple database design and all its saying is that you have to have some form of Media in order to store your Idea.

Comment: I could do this in Business Layer like David said. But I think it would be a better design if the database throws an error if an idea is generated without an existing media file.

Comment: @MUG4N: could you please describe what your tables hold.  I seem to be missing something that other people are picking up.  From your question I don't see how there is cross referencing.  It's a `1:>0` relationship.

Comment: If you can live with having to call a stored procedure to check this before committing a transaction inserting a idea/media group then you can do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is a design rule of thumb that a table models either a single entity type or a relationship between entity types but not both. Therefore, I envision three tables, `Media` (entity), `Idea` (entity) and `IdeasMedia` (relationship). p.s. you know the singular of 'media' is 'medium', right? :)

Here's some Standard SQL-92 DDL that focuses on keys only:

```
CREATE TABLE Media (MediaID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE Idea (IdeaID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE IdeasMedia 
(
 MediaID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Media (MediaID), 
 IdeaID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Idea (IdeaID)
);
CREATE ASSERTION Idea_must_have_media DEFERRABLE 
   CHECK (
          NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT * 
                        FROM Idea AS i 
                       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                         SELECT * 
                                           FROM IdeasMedia AS im 
                                          WHERE im.MediaID = i.IdeaID
                                        )
                     )
         );
```

There is a 'chicken and egg' scenario here: can't create an idea with without a referencing `IdeasMedia` but can't create an `IdeasMedia` without creating an `Idea`!

The ideal (set-based) solution would be for SQL Standard to support multiple assignment e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Media (MediaID) VALUES (22), 
   INSERT INTO Idea (IdeaID) VALUES (55), 
   INSERT INTO IdeasMedia (MediaID, IdeaID) VALUES (22, 55);
```

where the semicolon indicates the SQL statement boundary at which point constraints are checked and the commas denoting the sub-statements.

Sadly, there are no plans to add this set-based paradigm to the SQL Standard.

The SQL-92 (procedural) solution to this is as follows:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Media (MediaID) VALUES (22);
SET CONSTRAINTS Idea_must_have_media DEFERRED;
-- omit the above if the constraint was declared as INITIALLY DEFERRED.
INSERT INTO Idea (IdeaID) VALUES (55);
INSERT INTO IdeasMedia (MediaID, IdeaID) VALUES (55, 22);
SET CONSTRAINTS Idea_must_have_media IMMEDIATE;
-- above may be omitted: constraints are checked at commit anyhow.
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Sadly, SQL Server doesn't support `CREATE ASSERTION` nor `CHECK` constraints that can refer to other tables nor deferrable constraints!

Personally, I would handle this in SQL Server as follows:

- Create 'helper' stored procs to add, amend and remove `Ideas` and their respective
  `IdeasMedia` relationships.
- Remove update privileges from the tables to force users to use the
  procs.
- Possibly use triggers to handle scenarios when deleting `Media` and
  `Idea` entities.

Certainly, this (again procedural) implementation is far removed from the ideal set-based approach, which probably explains why most SQL coders turn a blind eye to a requirement for a 1:1..N relationship and instead assume the designer meant 1:0..N !!

Answer (score 1):

You create a `FK` (foreign key) in *Idea* to the `PK` (primary key) in *Media*.  At the same time apply a `NOT NULL` constraint to the FK.

If you already have data in the table, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423107/how-do-you-add-a-not-null-foreign-key-column-to-an-existing-populated-table-in)

---

To illustrate:

```
Media               Idea
-----               ----
 id | type           id | description       | media_id
----+-----          ----+-------------------+----------
 1  | TV             90 |  advertise        | 2
 2  | Magazine       90 |  advertise        | 1
 3  | Mail           91 |  superbowl party  | 1
                     91 |  superbowl party  | 3
```

I'm not saying this is great design, and I definitely don't know what your tables are storing (indicated by my poor example), but the idea cannot exist w/o a Media entry to link to.  There is no linking back and forth, you are asking for 1:N, not N:N, which you may want.

When thinking about the table names, it seems like your idea is backwards.  I would think you would have 1:Media to N:Ideas instead of the other way around.

---

```
CREATE TABLE idea (
    id        integer 
  , media_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES media
)  

--or--

CREATE TABLE idea (
    id         integer
  , media_id   NOT NULL
  , FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media
);
```

***Note:*** This is not normalized, so you would need a third table to match the joins.

Comment: So the two tables have foreign keys to each other? That would be kind of odd wouldn't it? And it also suffers from the 'chicken and egg' problem specified by Aleks G.

Comment: This means cross referencing ... I have heard bad things about cross references. Is this a common best practice? Or are there some best practices for this situation?

Comment: @David what do you mean, why would you have FK to eachother, there's only a one way FK from Idea to Media

Comment: I don't understand your answer, vol7ron. The OP is specific that 1 Idea can have many Media. Your FK from Idea to Media will produce the exact opposite relationship. When one needs relationship rules that aren't available within the basic permutations offered by the SQL relational model, that's when I think one needs business rules higher up.

Comment: @David: you're right, I was dyslexic.  The only way my answer makes any sort of sense is if you get rid of normalization, which I don't recommend.  I am going to delete this answer, sorry guys.