# How to enforce "at least one" in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, data-modeling

[image: ERD]

How to implement this relationship in PostgreSQL?
I need every meeting to have at least one session, but I do not how to realize it.

This is my try:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Meeting(
    MeetingId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Cost INT NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Session(
    SessId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATE NOT NULL,
    MeetingId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Meeting(MeetingId) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Should I add some new tables or constraints?

Comment: I think the foreign key should be in the other direction, from `meeting` to `session`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The description sounds like the OP wants to have multiple sessions per meeting, but guarantee that there is at least one.

Comment: This requirement is hard to represent as a SQL constraint since you have a chicken-and-egg problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10292355/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/7310121/1048572

Comment: @Bergi: The chicken-egg problem can be avoided.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'd argue that you still have the chicken-and-egg problem between the two rows. Even if there there is a solution for it, it requires special precautions to solve it.

Comment: @Bergi Fair enough. But since we have a simple solution, it's also fair to say we are avoiding the chicken-egg problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may seem like a chicken-egg problem, but there is a (mostly) simple solution that works perfectly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE meeting (
  meeting_id       int  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, first_session_id int  NOT NULL
, cost             int  NOT NULL
, startdate        date NOT NULL
, enddate          date NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE session (
  session_id       int  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, meeting_id       int  NOT NULL
, startdate        date NOT NULL
, enddate          date NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT session_meeting_id_fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id) REFERENCES meeting ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE   
, UNIQUE (meeting_id, session_id)  -- needed for FK meeting_first_session_id_fkey
);

ALTER TABLE meeting ADD CONSTRAINT meeting_first_session_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (meeting_id, first_session_id) REFERENCES session(meeting_id, session_id);  -- no cascading
```

Now, a meeting cannot be inserted without also inserting a session. And referential integrity is enforced at all times.
To avoid another lurking chicken-egg problem, use a data-modifying CTE to insert a meeting *and* its first session:

```sql
WITH ins_meeting AS (
   INSERT INTO meeting
          (first_session_id                                        , cost, startdate   , enddate)
   VALUES (nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('session', 'session_id')), 1   , '2023-03-08', '2023-03-09')
   RETURNING meeting_id, first_session_id
   )
INSERT INTO session (session_id, meeting_id, startdate, enddate)
SELECT first_session_id, meeting_id, '2023-03-08', '2023-03-09'
FROM   ins_meeting;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jfeHuec-)

This is optimized based on previous answers:

- [How to deal with mutually dependent inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813000/how-to-deal-with-mutually-dependent-inserts/24816197#24816197)
- [Chicken or Egg problem in table schema [PostgreSQL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244745/chicken-or-egg-problem-in-table-schema-postgresql/68245259#68245259)

About the demonstrated `IDENTITY` columns:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Note the use of `nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('session', 'session_id'))`. See:

- [Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433446#12433446)

A `PRIMARY KEY` column is `NOT NULL` implicitly. Spelling that out is optional noise. See:

- [Why can I create a table with PRIMARY KEY on a nullable column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006374/why-can-i-create-a-table-with-primary-key-on-a-nullable-column/20006502#20006502)
- [Composite PRIMARY KEY enforces NOT NULL constraints on involved columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642835/composite-primary-key-enforces-not-null-constraints-on-involved-columns/26643137#26643137)

Comment: So when i want to add the new meeting and session together use this insert sql? only add new session with old meeting use normal sql is ok? besides thanks for your answer, i think i may understand.

Comment: @朱哲昊 Yes to both questions.